# How to keep video quality same as it is after merge intro image beggining to video using ffmpeg

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, resolution, aspect-ratio, mobile-ffmpeg

I have selected high resolution video but once i run command the video resolution quality was changed and too poor quality's video i get as output video, but i don't would like to  loose my video quality. let me share full command and complete log below:

Note: libx264 encoder is not supporting iOS, I'm getting failure error so i use h264_videotoolbox so i would like to get supported command with h264_videotoolbox encoder

**Command:**

> ffmpeg -i test.MOV -loop 1 -t 5 -i 2.jpg -f lavfi -t 5 -i anullsrc
> -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=0:5,drawbox=t=fill[base];[1][base]scale2ref=iw:ih:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease:flags=spline[2nd][base2];[base2][2nd]overlay='(W-w)/2':'(H-h)/2'[padded];[padded][2:a][0:v][0:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]"
> -c:v h264_videotoolbox -c:a aac -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4

**Complete log**

```
ffmpeg version 4.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.4_1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test.MOV':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2021-03-07T06:36:17.000000Z
    com.apple.quicktime.location.accuracy.horizontal: 30.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.location.ISO6709: +23.1141+072.5768+061.729/
    com.apple.quicktime.make: Apple
    com.apple.quicktime.model: iPhone 6s
    com.apple.quicktime.software: 14.3
    com.apple.quicktime.creationdate: 2021-03-07T12:06:17+0530
  Duration: 00:00:29.79, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 15778 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 15643 kb/s, 29.98 fps, 29.97 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-03-07T06:36:17.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : H.264
  Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 89 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-03-07T06:36:17.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:2(und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-03-07T06:36:17.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Metadata
  Stream #0:3(und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-03-07T06:36:17.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Metadata
  Stream #0:4(und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 34 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-03-07T06:36:17.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Metadata
Input #1, image2, from '2.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 17347 kb/s
  Stream #1:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 360x360 [SAR 72:72 DAR 1:1], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #2, lavfi, from 'anullsrc':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 705 kb/s
  Stream #2:0: Audio: pcm_u8, 44100 Hz, stereo, u8, 705 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> trim
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> concat:in1:v0
  Stream #0:1 (aac) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #1:0 (mjpeg) -> scale2ref:default
  Stream #2:0 (pcm_u8) -> concat:in0:a0
  concat:out:v0 -> Stream #0:0 (h264_videotoolbox)
  concat:out:a0 -> Stream #0:1 (aac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x7f976242b000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt  
    com.apple.quicktime.creationdate: 2021-03-07T12:06:17+0530
    com.apple.quicktime.location.accuracy.horizontal: 30.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.location.ISO6709: +23.1141+072.5768+061.729/
    com.apple.quicktime.make: Apple
    com.apple.quicktime.model: iPhone 6s
    com.apple.quicktime.software: 14.3
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 30k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 h264_videotoolbox
  Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 69 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 aac
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   frame=   12 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:00.32 bitrate=6452.4kbits/frame=   34 fps= 32 q=-0.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:01.02 bitrate=2053.0kbits/frame=   55 fps= 35 q=-0.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:01.74 bitrate=1204.4kbits/frame=   76 fps= 37 q=-0.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:02.46 bitrate= 852.2kbits/frame=   98 fps= 38 q=-0.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:03.18 bitrate= 659.4kbits/frame=  120 fps= 39 q=-0.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:03.90 bitrate= 537.7kbits/frame=  141 fps= 39 q=-0.0 size=     512kB time=00:00:04.62 bitrate= 907.8kbits/[out_0_0 @ 0x7f975de0ae80] 100 buffers queued in out_0_0, something may be wrong.
[out_0_1 @ 0x7f975de0a5c0] 100 buffers queued in out_0_1, something may be wrong.
frame=  301 fps= 67 q=-0.0 size=     768kB time=00:00:11.09 bitrate= 566.9kbits/frame=  406 fps= 81 q=-0.0 size=    1024kB time=00:00:14.60 bitrate= 574.4kbits/frame=  509 fps= 92 q=-0.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:18.04 bitrate= 581.2kbits/frame=  604 fps=100 q=-0.0 size=    1792kB time=00:00:21.19 bitrate= 692.5kbits/frame=  705 fps=108 q=-0.0 size=    2048kB time=00:00:24.56 bitrate= 682.9kbits/frame=  809 fps=115 q=-0.0 size=    2304kB time=00:00:28.04 bitrate= 672.9kbits/frame=  909 fps=121 q=-0.0 size=    2816kB time=00:00:31.37 bitrate= 735.4kbits/frame= 1012 fps=126 q=-0.0 size=    3072kB time=00:00:34.71 bitrate= 725.0kbits/frame= 1043 fps=127 q=-0.0 Lsize=    3288kB time=00:00:34.78 bitrate= 774.3kbits/s speed=4.23x    
video:2995kB audio:255kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.168448%
[aac @ 0x7f9760024200] Qavg: 9569.656
```

Answer (score 0):

The main video have a bitrate aprox of 15778K, and this is a signal for quality hight...

> Duration: 00:00:29.79, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 15778 kb/s

You have to put bitrate parameter -b:v {bitrate, in this case 15778K}  in your code to keep hight qualiy, some like

```
ffmpeg -i test.MOV -loop 1 -t 5 -i 2.jpg -f lavfi -t 5 -i anullsrc -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=0:5,drawbox=t=fill[base];[1][base]scale2ref=iw:ih:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease:flags=spline[2nd][base2];[base2][2nd]overlay='(W-w)/2':'(H-h)/2'[padded];[padded][2:a][0:v][0:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -c:v h264_videotoolbox -b:v 15778K -c:a aac -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
```

---

NOTE: if have an error with "-c:a aac" parameter, remove it, because in Apple`s OS aac is for default because is an Apple codec

King Regards

Comment: Thanks @stevejobs I checked command with bitrate but getting below error

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libclang_rt.ubsan_osx_dynamic.dylib  
> Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/game-music-emu/lib/libgme.0.dylib  
> Reason: image not found zsh: abort      ffmpeg -i test.MOV -loop 1 -t
> 5 -i 2.jpg -f lavfi -t 5 -i anullsrc   -c:v

Comment: probe this:

brew upgrade node